# jQuery scrolling DIV is jumpy and positioned incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not too long ago I asked about setting up a DIV which scrolls with the rest of the page. Post can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647840/div-container-following-scroll-of-screen).

I've set this up, using the following code:

JS..

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var el = $('#sidebar'),
    pos = el.position().top;

    alert(pos);

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        el.toggleClass('fixed', $(this).scrollTop() >= pos);
    });
});
```

CSS..

```
/* profile sidebar */
#sidebar>div{ width: 300px; margin-top: 10px; }
#sidebar.fixed>div{position:fixed;top:0}
```

A copy of the page can be found [here](http://dunc.seriouslyfish.com/test.htm). The alert was just some debugging.

The problem is, when you scroll a small amount, `#sidebar` suddenly appears at the very top of the page. In addition, sometimes as you scroll further down, the sidebar appears - and sometimes it doesn't.

Any idea what might be causing such seemingly random functionality?

Comment: FYI - your example link is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still trying to figure out why it works in the first place in the jsfiddle example, but anyway, I know how to fix it:

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() >= pos){
        el.addClass('fixed');
    }else{
        el.removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

I tested this by unbinding the event you had and replacing it with this code. It seemed to work fine.

The reason I can't understand why it works in the example: <strike>toggleClass should be constantly adding and removing "fixed" if you have scrolled enough, because the conditional is true (true here means whether to toggle). The constant adding and removing of the fixed class causes the jumpy behavior.</strike>

You can watch this on your page: open up some dev tools (firegubg or Chrome) and watch what happens to your sidebar element.

[UPDATE]

Actually, I misread the docs. True means the class should be added (I don't think the docs are very clear though). Thus... the only way I could explain this is if @dunc was running jQuery v1.2 and the switch was getting ignored completely...

Comment: Beautiful Jere, thanks :) If you do work out why the JSFiddle example worked, let me know - it confuses me somewhat too!

Comment: Even weirder: It works on a simple fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pEMPK/. And the conditional being `true` just means that we want to add the class in that case (check the docs closely)

Comment: I think it's just two different behaviors of toggleClass. In the example, it is acting like true means "add the class" and false means "remove the class". On the page you posted, it is acting like true means "just toggle the class" and false means "don't toggle the class." The only way this makes sense is if you were running with version <1.3 before the switch argument was added. But it looks like you have 1.7.1 so I am clueless.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker, I actually thought the part about switch was ambiguous. You are definitely right about the intended behavior, but "A boolean value to determine whether the class should be added or removed." isn't clear.

Comment: It's not hard to understand.  You scroll, so it fires the toggle (on or off) upon every increment (1 pixel?) of scroll, as long as the condition is met.

Comment: Apparently, it is hard to understand because you just described the behavior incorrectly. It doesn't toggle if the conditional is met, it ADDS the class (not toggles) if the conditional is met.

Comment: @Sparky672: That's simply not how the function is documented to work. Read the documentation for `toggleClass` carefully. This answer should be logically equivalent to what the OP had originally. See the fiddle I posted above.

Comment: Yet, on the OP's page, it is clearly firing a toggle on/off as you scroll each increment.  @AndrewWhitaker, ok, now I see what you mean, and cannot explain why your Fiddle is operating differently than the OP's code.

Comment: It's jQuery 1.7.1 on the OP's page here:  http://dunc.seriouslyfish.com/test_files/jquery_003.js

Comment: @Sparky672 Yes, I know. I checked that too. That's why I am still confused.

Comment: I have not looked yet, but I assume you also check that his page's source code matches what he posted in his OP.  I read the doc's and now fully agree with you and Andrew.  Although, I think calling it "toggle" is somewhat counterintuitive, since, as you stated, it's "adding" when condition is true, not toggling.

Comment: Exactly, I agree! I did unbind and replace the page code with the OP's code (thinking that it would work), but it still didn't. It's always possible toggleClass is getting overwritten from some code on the page we don't know about. I wouldn't know how to check that (beyond the nonstandard behavior) and it's farfetched anyway.

Comment: @Jere is it possible to stop the scrolling div say 100 pixels off the bottom? Just realised it's getting in the way of my footer at the very bottom of the page.

Comment: Possible, but it's going to take a little bit of extra work. Let me get back to you on that... or you may consider opening a new question.